# Mostrar datos con resultado en cero mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos que realiza consultas para saber las cantidades de información detallada de cada tabla, las cuales se ordenan a través de una "tabla país". Cuando efectúa la consulta, aparece solo la información que contiene datos, por ejemplo:

en la tabla país existen 4 datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y 10 datos en las siguientes tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando se realizan las consultas a la tabla organización

```
SELECT 
pais.codigo_pais,
pais.descrip_pais,
Count(organizaciones.codigo_org) AS CUENTA,

FROM
organizaciones
Inner Join pais ON pais.codigo_pais = organizaciones.codigo_pais
GROUP BY
organizaciones.codigo_pais
```

me da como resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando consulto a las otras dos tablas reuniones

```
SELECT 
pais.codigo_pais,
pais.descrip_pais,
Count(reuniones.codigo_reu) AS CUENTA
FROM
reuniones
Inner Join pais ON reuniones.codigo_pais = pais.codigo_pais

GROUP BY
reuniones.codigo_pais
```

y compromisos

```
SELECT 
pais.codigo_pais,
pais.descrip_pais,
Count(compromisos.codigo_reu) AS CUENTA
FROM
compromisos
Inner Join pais ON compromisos.codigo_pais = pais.codigo_pais

GROUP BY
compromisos.codigo_pais
```

aparece este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que la consulta me muestre el país que registra el valor "0" en las tablas cuenta2 y cuenta3. En este caso, incluiría el registro de Alemania, como en el ejemplo a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te felicito. Así deberían hacerse todas las preguntas de tipo SQL. Clara y con todos los detalles que se requieren.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que aparezcan todos los países siempre, entonces debes primero usar la tabla `pais` y hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con la otra tabla:

```
SELECT  p.codigo_pais,
        p.descrip_pais,
        Count(r.codigo_reu) AS CUENTA
FROM pais p
LEFT JOIN reuniones r
    ON r.codigo_pais = p.codigo_pais
GROUP BY p.codigo_pais,
         p.descrip_pais
;
```

Otras recomendaciones: Trata siempre de usar alias de tablas, en vez de usar la tabla completa como prefijo, esto mejora la comprensión del código. Además, trata de acostumbrarte a usar código que sea más estándar en SQL, por ejemplo al momento de usar funciones de agregación. MySQL es el único motor de bases de datos relacionales que te permite usar una función de agregación en conjunto con otras columnas en el `SELECT`, y no poner esas columnas en el `GROUP BY` (esto entrega un resultado con un comportamiento arbitrario y muchas veces inesperado)